# How can I stop this text typing animation from looping?

Tags: javascript, loops

I don't understand **what** makes this animation start over and over again and **how** can I stop this after playing once. Can somebody help me please?
To find out which part of the code is responsible for the loop, I deleted different parts of the code one by one to see how the result is affected, but I still couldn't find it.

this is the HTML:

```
        <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hello.", "My name is B.", "I am just starting with  HTML, CSS and JavaScript.", "Please bear with me..."]'>
          <span class="wrap"></span>
        </a>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
          new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #f6fd96}";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation loop happens at the end of the `TxtType.prototype.tick` function, when the function calls itself again, recursively:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta)
```

`setTimeout` is a function that runs something after some time. In that case, it is running `that.tick()` after `delta` time.

If you want it to loop only once, you can use the `this.loopNum` information to make a condition around those lines above:

```js
if(this.loopNum < 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
    }, delta)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u used recursion to call the tick() function every delta ms.
This is where the loop is.

> ```
> TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
>     // ...
>     setTimeout(function() {
>     that.tick();
>     }, delta);
> }
> ```

If you want to just this code once. Please add the stop condition for the recursion.

```
if (this.loopNum < this.toRotate.length) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
}
```